# pick url of previous before page

Tags: asp.net

I have three pages,..say Page1, Page2, Page3.

User clicks a link in Page1 and redirects to Page2 fills a form and sumit which redirects to page3(Thankyou.aspx)

I want to place a OK button in Page3 which should redirect to Page1.

I can't hard code it bcoz it should be dynamic

Note: Page1 can be any other page , Page 2 can be any other form but in Page3 i want to track the 1st page from where the process is done.

I know something like :

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer
```

But it gives you the previous page but not the first page.

Can it be achievable.

Thanks in advance

Comment: don't you want to use WizardControl?

Comment: I guess the reason not to use a wizard is because of the dynamic nature of what pages are used. Although I agree, that a good design might use a wizard control with dynamically loaded forms in the shape of UserControls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also do this with javascript if you want to. You can hook it directly on your Ok button like this:

```
btnOk.Attributes.Add("onClick", "javascript:history.go(-2); return false;");
```

or you can register it on your page using a `ClientScriptManager` (from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/asz8zsxy.aspx)):

```
    // Define the name and type of the client scripts on the page.
    String csname = "GoBackScript";
    Type cstype = this.GetType();          

    // Get a ClientScriptManager reference from the Page class.
    ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;

    // Check to see if the startup script is already registered.
    if (!cs.IsStartupScriptRegistered(cstype, csname))
    {
        String scriptText= "<script type=\"text/javascript\">" +
               "window.history.go(-2);</" + "script>";     
        cs.RegisterStartupScript(cstype , csname, scriptText);
    }
```

Comment: +1 Not a bad answer. I would suggest you edit it a little to only call the history.go method on the click event of the OK button. Also, be aware that you don't need to include the script tags if you use the ClientScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript Method instead: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9h4dk8y.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be to store the page1 url in the user's session cache

```
Session["page1"] = HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer
```

Then when you get to page3 you have access to it. Make sure that after you use it, you remove it from the session cache, to make sure that you never get any old urls.

Comment: You are right but if you see my post it says Page1 can be any other PageX, so only i have do some coding in Page3 which is fainal page for all. So, how to handle it in Page3